# Set binding from code dont work in xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to use accordion in my xamarin.forms app.I can use it without any problems But when I want to use this with viewmodels.No data is shown in accordion 
.My viewmodel is like this ;

```
 namespace xamarinapp
{
   public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceWrapper _myServiceWrapper;
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public string viemodelName { get; set; }

        private bool UserLogCheck = false;
        private ObservableRangeCollection<dataInfro> _Acclist;
        public ObservableRangeCollection<Models.dataInfro> Acclist
        {
            get
            {
                return _Acclist;
            }
            set
            {
                _Acclist = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged(() => Acclist);
            }
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            UserLogCheck = DependencyService.Get<LoginInterface>().LoginExists();
            if (!UserLogCheck)
            {
                NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<LoginViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
              await  getData();
            }
        }
        public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand2 => new Command<dataInfro>(OntaptedItem);
        private async void OntaptedItem(dataInfro item)
        {

            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<OgrenciNotViewModel>(item.ogrId.ToString());

        }
        public TestViewModel(IServiceWrapper myServiceWrapper)
        {
            _myServiceWrapper = myServiceWrapper;
            _Acclist = new ObservableRangeCollection<dataInfro>();

        }
        private async Task getData()
        {
            ServiceWrapper serviceWrapper = new ServiceWrapper();
            var loginUser = DependencyService.Get<LoginInterface>().getAccount();
            var data =  await _myServiceWrapper.GetDataSecure<Ogrencilik>("GetDataUrl", loginUser);
            Acclist =new ObservableRangeCollection<dataInfro>(data.dataCollect);
        }
    }

}
```

And the accordion custom control is like this.(from https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com.tr/2016/10/build-accordion-view-in-xamarinforms.html )

```
namespace xamarinapp
{
    public class DefaultTemplate : AbsoluteLayout
    {
        public DefaultTemplate()
        {
            this.Padding = 0;
            this.HeightRequest = 50;
            var title = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
            var price = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
            this.Children.Add(title, new Rectangle(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            this.Children.Add(price, new Rectangle(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "name", stringFormat: "{0:c1}");
            price.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "balance", stringFormat: "{0:C2}");
        }
    }

    public class AccordionView : ScrollView
    {
        private StackLayout _layout = new StackLayout { Spacing = 1 };

        public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate SubTemplate { get; set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "ItemsSource",
                returnType: typeof(IList),
                declaringType: typeof(AccordionSectionView),
                defaultValue: default(IList),
                propertyChanged: AccordionView.PopulateList);

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public AccordionView()
        {
            var itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DefaultTemplate));
            this.SubTemplate = itemTemplate;
            this.Template = new DataTemplate(() => (object)(new AccordionSectionView(itemTemplate, this)));
            this.Content = _layout;
        }

        void PopulateList()
        {
            _layout.Children.Clear();

            foreach (object item in this.ItemsSource)
            {
                var template = (View)this.Template.CreateContent();
                template.BindingContext = item;
                _layout.Children.Add(template);
            }
        }

        static void PopulateList(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (oldValue == newValue) return;
            ((AccordionView)bindable).PopulateList();
        }
    }

    public class AccordionSectionView : StackLayout
    {
        private bool _isExpanded = false;
        private StackLayout _content = new StackLayout { HeightRequest = 0 };
        private Color _headerColor = Color.FromHex("0067B7");
        private ImageSource _arrowRight = ImageSource.FromFile("ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp.png");
        private ImageSource _arrowDown = ImageSource.FromFile("ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_24dp.png");
        private AbsoluteLayout _header = new AbsoluteLayout();
        private Image _headerIcon = new Image { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        private Label _headerTitle = new Label { TextColor = Color.White, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, HeightRequest = 50 };
        private DataTemplate _template;

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "ItemsSource",
                returnType: typeof(IList),
                declaringType: typeof(AccordionSectionView),
                defaultValue: default(IList),
                propertyChanged: AccordionSectionView.PopulateList);

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "Title",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(AccordionSectionView),
                propertyChanged: AccordionSectionView.ChangeTitle);

        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }

        public AccordionSectionView(DataTemplate itemTemplate, ScrollView parent)
        {
            _template = itemTemplate;
            _headerTitle.BackgroundColor = _headerColor;
            _headerIcon.Source = _arrowRight;
            _header.BackgroundColor = _headerColor;

            _header.Children.Add(_headerIcon, new Rectangle(0, 1, .1, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            _header.Children.Add(_headerTitle, new Rectangle(1, 1, .9, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

            this.Spacing = 0;
            this.Children.Add(_header);
            this.Children.Add(_content);

            _header.GestureRecognizers.Add(
                new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    Command = new Command(async () =>
                    {
                        if (_isExpanded)
                        {
                            _headerIcon.Source = _arrowRight;
                            _content.HeightRequest = 0;
                            _content.IsVisible = false;
                            _isExpanded = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _headerIcon.Source = _arrowDown;
                            _content.HeightRequest = _content.Children.Count * 50;
                            _content.IsVisible = true;
                            _isExpanded = true;

                            // Scroll top by the current Y position of the section
                            if (parent.Parent is VisualElement)
                            {
                                await parent.ScrollToAsync(0, this.Y, true);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            );
        }

        void ChangeTitle()
        {
            _headerTitle.Text = this.Title;
        }

        void PopulateList()
        {
            _content.Children.Clear();

            foreach (object item in this.ItemsSource)
            {
                var template = (View)_template.CreateContent();
                template.BindingContext = item;
                _content.Children.Add(template);
            }
        }

        static void ChangeTitle(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (oldValue == newValue) return;
            ((AccordionSectionView)bindable).ChangeTitle();
        }

        static void PopulateList(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (oldValue == newValue) return;
            ((AccordionSectionView)bindable).PopulateList();
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to set binding like this

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
    public partial class PageOgrenciNotModal : ContentPage
    {
        public PageOgrenciNotModal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            Accorview.SetBinding(AccordionView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Acclist");
            Accorview.Template.SetBinding(AccordionSectionView.TitleProperty, "Title");
            Accorview.Template.SetBinding(AccordionSectionView.ItemsSourceProperty, "List");
        }
    }
```

But nothing is happen.(note:there is no problem in getting data ,I can use same approach with listview with no problems).Any help is appreciated ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a MVVM Framework you have to set the `BindingContext` of the page yourself.

So do something like:

```
public PageOgrenciNotModal()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new TestViewModel();

}
```

Comment: Yes I know ,I  doing this  while navigation.So no problem in setting viewmodel in page.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I doing this while navigation"? You should always set the BindingContext in the constructor and we don't see that in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
Accorview.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Accorlist");
```

looks suspicious.

IMHO, it should be

```
Accorview.SetBinding(AccordionView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Accorlist");
```

Comment: sorry ,I wrote wrong in here,I already used by that way .I tried to check if data is coming by binding a listview from code ,and no problem because  listview is binded.